# Is there a .net pivot table control that I can use on jquery, asp.net application without using SSAS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pivot-table

A non silverlight based pivot table is required.

i want to expose data in a pivot table but the data is in MS SQL 2008 DB.

i don't want to use SSAS.  Is there a control that can get data from SQL and allow user to create a pivot table? preferably in .net

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in ASP.NET pivot table controls, I would recommend you looking at:

- [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/MVC/)
- [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet-mvc)
- [Telerik (RadPivotGrid)](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/pivotgrid.aspx)

If you are interested in JS pivot table controls, I would recommend you checking the following ones:

- [Flexmonster](http://www.flexmonster.com/demo-all-in-one/)
- [Telerik (Kendo UI PivotGrid)](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pivotgrid)
- [PivotTable.js](http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Reports, you could make a report that uses a matrix. I did find [jqPivotTable](http://code.google.com/p/jqpivottable/) in my research, but it doesn't look promising. I have found plenty of Flash and Silverlight controls, but I, too, am looking for a pure javascript control.

OLAP-Based but HTML-rendered:

[icCube](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html?ic3demo) **navigate to the Pivot Table example under the Widget Examples on the left side of the page*

Other (even though you are not looking for them):

[FlexMonster](http://www.flexmonster.com/demos/pivot-table-js/)

[VIBlend](http://www.viblend.com/products/net/silverlight/controls/silverlight-olap-pivot-grid.aspx)

Comment: Actually, [flexmonster](http://www.flexmonster.com/demos/pivot-table-js/) is javascript pivot

Comment: @ira, Thanks. Updated answer and links.

Answer (score 0):

[webpivottable](http://webpivottable.com) may what you are looking for. Here is the [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) .

It's a pure javascript component so that you can integrate it into any web application, like your .NET application. No any plugin needed.

You can use it to pivot any csv format data or any OLAP cubes directly. And you can also use the API to load your own data. For example, you can use SQL to get data from database, then set the data into the component,  Here is the [document](http://webpivottable.com/documents) .